# How do I unzip apk after build with different build variants?

Tags: android, gradle

I am struggling with writing a task which will unzip an apk. I have several Build Variants, and I want to dynamically create a task for each of them.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant -> variant.outputs.all { output ->
    def assembleTaskName = 'assemble' + variant.getName().capitalize()
    def outputDir = new File(output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toString() + "\\tmp") 
    def apk = output.outputFile //there is some code which generates correct apk name based on Build Variant
    tasks.getByName(assembleTaskName).finalizedBy(task("unzip" + apk.name, type: Zip) {
        outputDir.mkdirs()
        from zipTree(apk)
        into outputDir
    })
}}
```

While this code creates tmp folder where I need it, apk doesn't get extracted, and this code seems to run on every build variant I have, but I only need it to run on the one I build right now. How can I do that?